# Add multiple values to data attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is the code.

```
<body>
<div class="test" >Test</div>

<script>
var count =1;
$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {

    $('.test').attr('data-count',count);
    count ++;
})
```

I want to add multiple values to data-count like this, data-count="1,2,3,4". How can i do that ?

Comment: If you comma-separate the values in the `data` attribute, how are you planning on reading them back in — have you thought about that?

Comment: basically i am planning to use shuffle.js and for that i need to set multiple values to data attribute. Based on my code above, everytime i click, i need to add this value dynamically to data-count, would appreciate if you can correct my code.

Comment: @user3751873 - You may accept the answer that you found most helpful by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without global variables:

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        count = $this.data('i') || 1,
        $test = $('.test');

    count++;
    $this.data('i', count);

    var result = [];

    for(var i = 1; i < count; i++){
        result.push(i);
    }

    $test.attr('data-count', result.toString());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7ny77s9/

Comment: or `$test.data('count', result);` and `$test.data('count')` to get the array back. I know the answer is old, that's why posted this comment so you can update your answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;
var countArr = [];
$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
    countArr.push(count);
    $('.test').attr('data-count', countArr.join(","));
    count ++;
});
```

Edit: without using the second variable

```
var count = 1;

$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {    
  var testVal = $('.test').attr('data-count') === undefined ? count : $('.test').attr('data-count') + "," + count;
  $('.test').attr('data-count', testVal);
    count ++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot Alok it worked, i didnt see any example on jquery website, why is this so ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Alok Swain's Answer, saving `data-*` `count` as an array at the element

```
var count = 1;
var arr = [];
$(".test").data("count", arr);
$('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
    $('.test').data("count", arr.push(count));
    count++;
});
```